# Multi Select Listbox (Same Form - Submission) - On Error - Display Selected Values

Tags: javascript, listbox

ON FIRST TIME  LOAD -

Read the values from the table field into a variable

If field is blank - then dont do anything

Just populate the listbox from default element custom values

ON SUBMIT (SAME PAGE) -MULTIPLE VALUES SELECTED

On Submit, Store the “selected value”s from listbox in an array in a hidden element

or a temp persistent variable or > maybe a hidden virtual field

ON ERROR - REFRESH

If theres an error:- Example: Other required fields are not filled in on form (The selected hidden values are not yet committed to the database)

Then

Load the hidden “selected values” array

In the Listbox - Match the hidden “selected values” array <<>> with the drop down list element custom values

Finally- Highlight and show the values in the listbox as selected .

IF NO ERROR

Then submit values in delimited string to table field.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo here](http://codepen.io/hotdudehvfun/pen/ZLOqxY)
Multiple elements can be selected

```
    <select onclick="getValues();" id="cars" name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<p>Selecting item will toggle its state:</p>
<p id='output'>Selected Item:</p>





var values=new Array();
var cars=document.getElementById("cars")
function getValues()
{
    var index=values.indexOf(cars.value);
    if (index > -1) 
      values.splice(index, 1);
    else
        values.push(cars.value);
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML="Selected Item:"+values.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Arun, Thanks that did work, Thanks.  but I realized I incorrectly phrased my goal for the script. I have posted pseudo code as to what Im  trying to achieve.Thank YOU.